# Python - Vertica Library database connection issue

Tags: python, database, oracle, vertica, vertica-python

from vertica_python import connect
conn_info = {'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx',
'port': 1521,
'user': 'username#',
'password': 'password#',
'database': 'Training_DB_Name'}
connection = connect(**conn_info)

Using the code above, I am trying to connect to an oracle db and do some sql queries via python.(the DB is in another server) not sure if technically I need an SSL? Please explain because I dont even know what SSL is The issue I am encountering is the following:

--> 328 self.startup_connection()
330 # Initially, for a new session, autocommit is off
331 if self.options['autocommit']:
...
580     self._logger.error(err_msg)
--> 581     raise errors.ConnectionError(err_msg)
583 return raw_socket

ConnectionError: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.

Comment: Is that library not specifically for connecting to Vertica DBs, rather than Oracle or other DBs?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed: VerticaPy lives and dies with Vertica. Even the key-value pairs of the JDBC/ODBC connection strings differ between Oracle and Vertica. You won't even be able to connect to a database other than Vertica